# Convert time to string in PHP

Tags: php, date

I want to add a programs based on time. that is for example a program named "ABC" added with time 11:00 AM to 02:00 AM. Then every day when time interval 11:00 AM to 02:00 PM the program ABC should display.

I tried 
When add --

```
$timefrom  = strtotime('11:00 AM');
$timeto = strtotime('02:00 PM');
```

it will store in the database.And in the front end

```
$current_time = strtotime(date("h:i A"));
$current_day = date("l");
$query_pbanner = "SELECT pgm_banner FROM rj_prog WHERE ('$current_time' BETWEEN `prog_from` AND `prog_to`) AND ('$current_day' = `week_name`)";
```

But when date change it will not woking.is there any way to convert time only to string and compare.

Comment: What do you mean time to string? strototime converts a string into the unixtimestamp. - please also clarify what you mean by "not working" what error are you getting?

Comment: yes but it will depends on the date also ryt?...i only want time tio compare

Comment: A unixtimestamp is seconds since 1970 something, again, I'm not entirely sure what it is you are trying to achieve. - Or what is going wrong for that matter

Comment: i want to add program which have a time duration like radio program say 11:00 Am to 02:00 PM. then every day when time is in that interval i want to display that program...thats all

Answer (score 0):

I have just edited your query and it seems to return to me correct program name

SELECT pgm_banner FROM rj_prog WHERE ('$current_time' BETWEEN prog_from AND prog_to) AND ('$current_day' = week_name)

Comment: The column names were getting passed as strings